# Specify Behave table row data type

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd, python-behave

Here I've written a test to determine if an API is responding to a bad request with the expected content...

```
Scenario: Unkown user response body properties contain expected content
    Given I have a valid client auth token
    And I request a user with an unknown "valid" uuid
    And I get the response json
    Then the expected fields should contain expected content
    | field      | content               |
    | statusCode | 404                   |
    | error      | Not Found             |
    | message    | User record not found |
```

This is the corresponding step:

```
@then(u'the expected fields should contain expected content')
def step_impl(context):
    for row in context.table:
        received_content = str(context.request_json.get(row['field']))
        expected_content = row['content']
        assert_equal(received_content, expected_content)
```

It seems that Behave converts table row content to strings.

My question is: Is it possible to specify the data type of a cell in a Behave table?

In the actual response `statusCode` is an integer, but as you can see in my step function I'm forced to convert the request content to a string in order to validate it. I wouldn't need to do this if I could specify that the `404` I'm passing in the content column is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your scenario as

```
Given I have a valid client auth token
And I request a user with an unknown "valid" uuid
Then I should get user not found response
```

Then you can put all the details of what a user not found response is in a helper method. This gives you:

- a simple scenario
- no table processing for your scenario
- a method you can reuse in other scenarios where a user is not found
- much lower cost of change if for example you want to ad another field to the response.

In general keeping details of HOW you do things out of your scenarios makes them much simpler to implement and much cheaper to maintain.

Hope ^^ is of some use :)

Comment: This is great thank you, didn't even think of approaching the problem like this :)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to specify data types for columns in a behave table, though not necessarily possible for specific rows within the columns. See this [tutorial](https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial10.html). It explains implementing User-Defined Types by using behave's `register_type`.

Another option is to use behave's [parser](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#step-parameters). This is as close to what you're looking for as I've found.

Comment: register_type is not applicable to tables in behave

Comment: @Fine is that from your experience or in the documentation somewhere? The linked "tutorial" applied directly to OP's question and, from what I just gathered from the documentation, it doesn't seem to have changed in the past 4 years since the original question...

Comment: The question was about typing in [Table in Behave's Step Data](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#step-data), but your tutorial only works for [Behave's Scenario Outline](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#scenario-outlines) which is a different mechanism even if it looks like a table too.